# Will killing guardsmen affect how people interact with you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

Inside palaces in Arena (or at least in the palace in Rihad, Hammerfell) there is a back area that when you begin walking inside it says "Restricted Area! Authorized personnel only!" If you continue walking in there, which I did, a Warrior will come back and attack you. I killed the Warrior and walked back into the Main Hall without anyone else attacking me, but will people in the palace like me less now? Or will I become a felon and guards will attack me?

Or does the game not have anything as advanced as that and it will progress as if nothing had happened? Thanks!

Comment: Wait, sorry, why the downvote? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Your question looks fine to me, people can choose to vote for whatever reasons they want.  Keep up the good posting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Elder Scrolls: Arena has no crime/bounty system like later games in the series. If you kill the guard sent to stop you, there will be no negative consequences whatsoever.

Comment: Awesome, you're sure of this? I believe you but just wondering if you have a source?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about crime on the [Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Crime), and I found [this discussion](http://www.gamesas.com/question-about-crime-arena-t49204.html) mentioning the absence of a crime system.

Comment: Perfect, good enough for me! Thanks for the answer! But do you want me to edit the question in any way so that you don't downvote it?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, though I didn't upvote it either.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Only saw you interact with this question.

Comment: [Here's a reference](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:General_Hints#Guards) from the UESP: "there is no bounty system in the game, so you can escape outside of a town or into a building if you set off the guards"